# SpringMVC RequestMapping for GET parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to make the RequestMapping to handle GET parameters in the url?
For example i have this url

```
http://localhost:8080/userGrid?_search=false&nd=1351972571018&rows=10&page=1&sidx=id&sord=desc
```

(from jqGrid)

how should my RequestMapping look like? I want to get the parameters using HttpReqest

Tried this:

```
@RequestMapping("/userGrid")
    public @ResponseBody GridModel getUsersForGrid(HttpServletRequest request)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use [@RequestParam](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) in your method arguments so Spring can bind them, also use the [@RequestMapping.params](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params%28%29) array to narrow the method that will be used by spring. Sample code:

```
@RequestMapping("/userGrid", 
params = {"_search", "nd", "rows", "page", "sidx", "sort"})
public @ResponseBody GridModel getUsersForGrid(
@RequestParam(value = "_search") String search, 
@RequestParam(value = "nd") int nd, 
@RequestParam(value = "rows") int rows, 
@RequestParam(value = "page") int page, 
@RequestParam(value = "sidx") int sidx, 
@RequestParam(value = "sort") Sort sort) {
// Stuff here
}
```

This way Spring will only execute this method if ALL PARAMETERS are present saving you from null checking and related stuff.

Comment: What if I don't want all of them every time, can they be optional? Also, what if I have a lot of params? Can I just create a class with params and put the class as @RequestParam? Thanks!

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable to know about optional parameters

Comment: Does this work? How should the Sort object look like in the URL? I tried with the `?object[key]=value` format and it didn't work

Comment: To make parameters optional in newer versions of Spring (4+) use `required=false` and `Optional<T>` as parameter type e.g. `@RequestParam(value="sort",required=false) Optional<String> sort`

Answer (score 32):

You can add `@RequestMapping` like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/userGrid")
public @ResponseBody GridModel getUsersForGrid(
   @RequestParam("_search") String search,
   @RequestParam String nd,
   @RequestParam int rows,
   @RequestParam int page,
   @RequestParam String sidx) 
   @RequestParam String sord) {
```

Comment: Also you don't need `value = "myname"` if the method param and request param have the same name. I upvoted this answer though.

Answer (score 18):

This will get ALL parameters from the request. For Debugging purposes only:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/promote", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView renderPromotePage (HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();

    for(String key : parameters.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key);
        String[] vals = parameters.get(key);
        for(String val : vals)
            System.out.println(" -> " + val);
    }

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("test");
    return mv;
}
```

Comment: Does there also exist a possibility to get all mapped params + optionally ones that are not mapped yet? E.g. to detect if a client puts in parameters that aren't used. So one could log for this a warning?

Comment: @Strinder (Late response, but here for reference): If you have the method argument `@RequestParam(defaultValue = "{}") MultiValueMap<String, String>`, then you will get a `Map` where each value is a `List` of `String`s for the given `key`.  You could then iterate over this to see if there are any `key`s you don't recognise.  `Map<String, String>` works too, if you know for certain there won't be any repeated parameters.

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to change your uri, you could also use `PathVariable`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/foo/{foo}/{bar}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String process(@PathVariable String foo,@PathVariable String bar) {
    //Perform logic with foo and bar
}
```

**NB:** The first foo is part of the path, the second one is the `PathVariable`

Answer (score 2):

This works in my case:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savedata",
            params = {"textArea", "localKey", "localFile"})
    @ResponseBody
    public void saveData(@RequestParam(value = "textArea") String textArea,
                         @RequestParam(value = "localKey") String localKey,
                         @RequestParam(value = "localFile") String localFile) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write a kind of template into the `@RequestMapping`:

```
http://localhost:8080/userGrid?_search=${search}&nd=${nd}&rows=${rows}&page=${page}&sidx=${sidx}&sord=${sord}
```

Now define your business method like following:

```
@RequestMapping("/userGrid?_search=${search}&nd=${nd}&rows=${rows}&page=${page}&sidx=${sidx}&sord=${sord}")
public @ResponseBody GridModel getUsersForGrid(
@RequestParam(value = "search") String search, 
@RequestParam(value = "nd") int nd, 
@RequestParam(value = "rows") int rows, 
@RequestParam(value = "page") int page, 
@RequestParam(value = "sidx") int sidx, 
@RequestParam(value = "sort") Sort sort) {
...............
}
```

So, framework will map `${foo}` to appropriate `@RequestParam`.

Since sort may be either asc or desc I'd define it as a enum:

```
public enum Sort {
    asc, desc
}
```

Spring deals with enums very well.

Comment: what if the parameters change in order?

Comment: Good point, @mael. I typically used Spring MVC for Restful services where the parameters are specified into the URL itself and the order is pre-defined. I learned about `params` attribute now.