# Match requestmapping to old style urls

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a form that once submitted send requests like following

Form

```
       <form:form action="/edit" modelAttribute="edit" role="form" 
       method="GET">
```

Requests

```
/edit?param1=1&param2=&param3=
/edit?param1=1&param2=this & that$param3=
/edit?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3
```

I am doing as following but it does not work

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("edit")
public class Edit{
   ....
   @RequestMapping(value = "?param1={p1}&param2=&param3=", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

*Please note param names might include &

Comment: this might be of some help to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213061/springmvc-requestmapping-for-get-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of flexibility by adding a `@RequestParam Map<String, String> all` parameter e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(@RequestParam Map<String, String> all, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

this way all your parameters will be bound to the map `all`, where key will be the names of your parameter and value will be the value of the param

---

Alternatively, you can add a form backing bean, especially as you already have the `modelAttribute=edit` e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(FormBean edit, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

In your `FormBean` you can list all the possible parameter names as properties and they will get properly bound e.g.

```
public class FormBean {
    private String param1;

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }
}
```

Update after comment

you can also list all the possible parameters, and mark them as `required=false`, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "param1") String param, @RequestParam(required = false, value = "param2") String param,method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Note one thing, server will always use the existence of the `&` char in a query string as a parameter delimeter, that is why you can't have it as a parameter name

Comment: thanks, does that mean I would have one method only and need to have if condition / map contains function to find out which ones are passed? is not it possible to have separate method for each format of request?

Comment: Yes, you would have to go through the map list. I initially thought that you're looking for a way to map a dynamic set of params, but it is possible to have a separate method for each request, just list the param in `@RequestParam` and set the `required` flag accordingly, I've updated the answer with the example