# unable to pass parameters in <img> tag src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-mvc, get

I am developing a spring mvc web app , in one of the jsp's i am trying to display image in a dialog box :

my javascript function is as follows :

```
 function displayImageData(param1,param2,param3)
     {

         $('#dialog-image-data-div').dialog({
            modal:true,
            width: 1200, 
            height: "auto" ,
            resizable:false,
            autoOpen : false,
            position: ['center',70],//used for positioning the dialog   
        });//end of dialog method

         $('#dialog-image-data-div').dialog("open");
         $('#dialog-image-data-div').html(' <img src="fetchImageData?param1=${param1}"/> ');

     }
```

**Situation:**
The url in `src` attribute should divert control to a controller.
In controller a business service will take three parameters namely `param1` , `param2` and `param3` and fetch the image from db.

**Problem :**
My problem is i am not able to pass these three paramters in the url specified in `src` attribute and i also dont know what the `RequestMapping` of the method in controller will look like , i gave googled a lot but i am not able to find answers can anyone help ?

Comment: var src = "fetchImageData?param1=${param1}" then pass it to that img tag

Comment: i want o pass `param2` and `param3` also , and how will a assign varibale src to `src attribute of image`

Comment: var src = fetchImageData?param1=${param1}; $('#dialog-image-data-div').html(' <img src="'+ src +'"/> '); now chwck

Answer (score 0):

`displayImageData` will be called by the browser, the value of the parameters are not known to your JSP so it will not be able to use JSTL Expression Language `${param1}` to put them into your JavaScript string.

You just need to build the URL in JavaScript:

```
$('#dialog-image-data-div').html(' <img src="fetchImageData?param1='+param1+'&amp;param2='+param2+'&amp;param3='+param3+"/> ');
```

As for the request mappings in Spring, you just need to add a @RequestParam annotation for each parameter to your method.  See: [SpringMVC RequestMapping for GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213061/springmvc-requestmapping-for-get-parameters)