# Invalid <url-pattern> in servlet mapping how to remove this error

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, url-parameters

i am using this function for get request param spring3 mvc and my url is

localhost:8080/karmaFriend/register/abc/wq/abc@abc.com

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register/{username}/{password}/{email}",  method = RequestMethod.GET)

public @ResponseBody ResponseMsg getUserInJSON(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String password, @PathVariable String email) {
        ResponseMsg responseMsg = CommonUtils.checkParam(username, password, email);
        if(responseMsg.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("True"))
            responseMsg =  userService.registerUser(username, password, email);
        return responseMsg;
    }
```

it works good but if i change my url like this 
localhost:8080/karmaFriend/register/abc//abc@abc.com

then it will not call to that function ... is there any other way to call same function ??

Comment: it seems that you need to write a different method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4904139/322166

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to register someone without a username, but you can use regular expressions in your path variables.  Try changing username to "{username:^[\pL\pN\p{Pc}]*$}", which will hopefully gobble up 0 or more alpha-numerics with underscore characters.  You may have to play with the regex a bit.