# Spring MVC: how to indicate whether a path variable is required or not?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, path-variables

I am doing a Spring web. For a controller method, I am able to use RequestParam to indicate whether a parameter it is required or not. For example:

```
@RequestMapping({"customer"}) 
public String surveys(HttpServletRequest request, 
@RequestParam(value="id", required = false) Long id,            
Map<String, Object> map)
```

I would like to use PathVariable such as the following:

```
@RequestMapping({"customer/{id}"}) 
public String surveys(HttpServletRequest request, 
@PathVariable("id") Long id,            
Map<String, Object> map)
```

How can I indicate whether a path variable is required or not? I need to make it optional because when creating a new object, there is no associated ID available until it is saved.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think you're asking for the same thing as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Spring 3.0, can I make an optional path variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's no way to make it optional, but you can create two methods with one having the `@RequestMapping({"customer"})` annotation and the other having `@RequestMapping({"customer/{id}"})` and then act accordingly in each.

Comment: Tristan, I selected the VTTom's post as the answer to benefit whoever reads this question. Your was right.

Comment: It is possible, see some of the other answers (@curious1 feel free to accept one of the other answers).

Comment: it is possible to use that way:
`@PatchMapping(path = {"/{procurementInitId}/updateLinkedPurchase/{purchaseId}",
                                            "/{procurementInitId}/updateLinkedPurchase"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<?> updateLinkedPurchase(
            @PathVariable(name = "procurementInitId") Integer procurementInitId,
            @PathVariable(name = "purchaseId", required = false) Integer purchaseId) {`

Answer (score 63):

[VTTom`s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2095611/vttom) solution is right, just change "value" variable to array and list all url possibilities: value={"/", "/{id}"}

```
@RequestMapping(method=GET, value={"/", "/{id}"})
public void get(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> id) {
  if (id.isPresent()) {
    id.get()   //returns the id
  }
}
```

Comment: Note this requires Spring 4.1+ and Java 1.8.

Comment: When you use `"/"` you will get 404 for `http://.../foo/bar` address and response for `http://.../foo/bar/`. I used empty string `""` as first value.

Comment: Note that since Spring 4.3.3, you can also go with `@PathVariable(required = false)` and get null if the variable is not present.

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann, Thank you for the information, which is correct. But that only doesn't work. It could be like

`@RequestMapping(value = {"foo", "foo/{bar}"})`
and 
`@PathVariable(required = false)`

Comment: My comment is only an addition to the answer (which should be the accepted answer) in that it provides an alternative to making the id Optional.

Answer (score 35):

I know this is an old question, but searching for "optional path variable" puts this answer high so i thought it would be worth pointing out that since Spring 4.1 using Java 1.8 this is possible using the java.util.Optional class.

an example would be (note the value must list all the potential routes that needs to match, ie. with the id path variable and without. Props to @martin-cmarko for pointing that out)

```
@RequestMapping(method=GET, value={"/", "/{id}"})
public void get(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> id) {
  if (id.isPresent()) {
    id.get()   //returns the id
  }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone verify this works? I get 404 when I try to access this path without id (Spring MVC 4.1.4, Java 1.8.0_66).

Comment: Yes this will not work as path without id will not match and hit this controller.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the pkg name for Optional class.

Comment: This part `value={"/", "/{id}"}` makes it work on routes with and without id

Answer (score 3):

VTToms answer will not work as without id in path it will not be matched (i.e will not find corresponding `HandlerMapping`) and consequently controller will not be hit. Rather you can do -

```
@RequestMapping({"customer/{id}","customer"}) 
public String surveys(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariablesMap, Map<String, Object> map) {
    if (pathVariablesMap.containsKey("id")) {
        //corresponds to path "customer/{id}"
    }
    else {
        //corresponds to path "customer"
    }
}
```

You can also use `java.util.Optional` which others have mentioned but it requires requires Spring 4.1+ and Java 1.8..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but as none of the answers provide some updated information and as I was passing by this, I would like to add my contribution:

Since [Spring MVC 4.3.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html#required--) introduced [Web Improvements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.30.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#v4_3-Web-Improvements),

```java
@PathVariable(required = false) //true is default value
```

is legal and possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with using 'Optional'(@PathVariable Optional id)  or Map (@PathVariable Map pathVariables)  in that if you then try to create a HATEOAS link by calling the controller method it will fail because Spring-hateoas seems to be pre java8 and has no support for 'Optional'. It also fails to call any method with @PathVariable Map annotation.

Here is an example that demonstrates the failure of Map

```
   @RequestMapping(value={"/subs","/masterclient/{masterclient}/subs"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public List<Jobs>  getJobListTest(
         @PathVariable  Map<String, String> pathVariables,
         @RequestParam(value="count", required = false, defaultValue = defaultCount) int count) 
   {

      if (pathVariables.containsKey("masterclient")) 
      {
         System.out.println("Master Client = " + pathVariables.get("masterclient"));
      } 
      else 
      {
         System.out.println("No Master Client");
      }




  //Add a Link to the self here.
  List list = new ArrayList<Jobs>();
  list.add(linkTo(methodOn(ControllerJobs.class).getJobListTest(pathVariables, count)).withSelfRel());

  return list;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"/customer", "/customer/{id}"})
public String getCustomerById(@PathVariable("id") Optional<Long> id) 
        throws RecordNotFoundException 
{
    if(id.isPresent()) {
        //get specific customer
    } else {
        //get all customer or any thing you want
    }
}
```

> Now all URLs are mapped and will work.

> /customer/123

> /customer/1000

> /customer   -   WORKS NOW !!