# How to set default value to a path variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{locale}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getLocale(@PathVariable("locale") String locale) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(locale, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I want if locale is null, I can set a default value "english" in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620395/spring-set-default-pathvariable

Answer (score 2):

By default PathVariable is required but you can set it optional as :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{locale}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getLocale(@PathVariable(name="locale", required= 
false) String locale) {
//set english as default value if local is null   
locale = locale == null? "english": locale;
return new ResponseEntity<>(locale, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use required false attribute and then can check for null or empty string value. Refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620395/spring-set-default-pathvariable)

```
getLocale(@PathVariable(name ="locale", required= false) String locale
```

And then check for null or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide default value to spring path variable as of now.

You can do the following obvious thing:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{locale}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getLocale(@PathVariable("locale") String locale) {
    locale = locale == null? "english": locale;
    return new ResponseEntity<>(locale, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But more appropriate is to use Spring i18n.CookieLocaleResolver, so that you do not need that path variable anymore:

```
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set the required property of @PathVariable to false to make it optional.

But we will also need to listen for requests that are coming without path variable.

```
@GetMapping(value = { "/{locale}", "/" }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getLocale(@PathVariable("locale") String locale) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(locale, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to provide default value

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{locale}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getLocale(@PathVariable("locale", defaultValue="english") String locale) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(locale, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: there is no `defaultValue` in `@PathVariable`

Comment: there is nothing like defaultValue