# REST URI design issue

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, uri

We are developing banking web services in spring mvc and trying to comply with Rest Uri Design principals. As you know in banking applications you can do eft(electronic funds transfer),  credit card debt payments, money orders, bill payments, etc. Actually these financial operations create transactions on your bank account. So we think the URIs must be like this:

To get transactions for specific account :

```
GET   /users/{id}/accounts/{id}/transactions
```

To do card debt payment :

```
POST  /users/{id}/accounts/{id}/transactions?type=card
```

To do eft :

```
POST  /users/{id}/accounts/{id}/transactions?type=eft
```

To do money order :

```
POST  /users/{id}/accounts/{id}/transactions?type=moneyorder
```

In this case in my controller there will be only one method that serves all this different actions. This method is going to get type of the action from the RequestParam and decide the action in if/else blocks. But this is disapproved according to Java Design Principals. Because adding new transaction types is going to add additional if/else blocks in that method.

So what will be the best solution for this issue.
Different approaches will be appreciated.

Comment: Have You considered making `type` a path param, and writing separate mapping for each type ? There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable) that has been already answered...

Comment: You mean a uri like this : POST  /users/{id}/accounts/{id}/transactions/{type}. But there is no relation between account transactions and transaction type.

Comment: You can map separate types to different methods. So instead of making `{type}` param, make it static part of path and map it by path to methods  (`/card` , `/efs`, `/`, etc.). If You want to keep it as a param, experiment with static param value and requedt mapping