# How to handle requests that contain forward slashes?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

My URL request is `http://localhost:8080/login/verify/212,32,/cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,/SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo=`

I need get the following part: `**212,32,/cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,/SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo=**`.

The following code doesn't work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/verify/{request:.+}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    public ResponseEntity verifyLogin(@PathVariable(value = "request") String request)
            throws InvalidSignatureException
    {
}
```

Error: HTTP Status 404.

Spring can't handle this request.

Comment: Can you write it as:
 (http://localhost:8080/login/verify/212/32/cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,/SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo=) ?
where "212", "32" and "cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,/SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo=" will be different parameters. Do you want so?

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, i need parse entire string, which contain 4 parametrs, divided ",". Sometimes the 4 parameter can contain slash (/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the uri with the slashes,  use the double *

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/verify/**",
```

Then,  in the body to get the value,  you will use

```
String str = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Sample code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/verify/**", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}) 
public ResponseEntity verifyLogin(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws InvalidSignatureException {
    String str = (String) request.getAttribute( HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE)
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks. Where request is HttpServletRequest. @RequestMapping(value = "/login/verify/**", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
 public ResponseEntity verifyLogin(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
   throws InvalidSignatureException
 {String str = (String) request.getAttribute( HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE)}

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL instead: `http://localhost:8080/login/verify?req=212,32,/cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,/SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo=`

And handle it like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/login/verify")
public String test(@RequestParam("req") String data) {
    //'data' will contains '212,32,/cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x,/SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo='
   String params[] = data.split(",");
}
```

Comment: I can't, the request is not formed by me. I can't use query parametrs

Answer (score 0):

You have forward slashes in your url and those strings will be considered as path variables. Try the following code if there is a possibility that you'll have only 3 path variables. Please have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421061/how-to-handle-requests-that-includes-forward-slashes)

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login/verify/{string1:.+}",
        "/login/verify/{string1:.+}/{string2:.+}",
        "/login/verify/{string1:.+}/{string2:.+}/{string3:.+}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity verifyLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpresponse, 
        @PathVariable("string1") String string1,
        @PathVariable("string2") String string2,
        @PathVariable("string3") String string3) {
    System.out.println("***************************************************I am called: "+string1+" "+string2+" "+string3);
```

}

Comment: I know about this solution, but in this case i get string1 = 212, string2 =32, string3 = cntv5tag07rmy791wbme7xa8x, string4 = SSNZclzqhhH7v6uHIkUsIcPusKo=. string 3 and string4 without slash(/), i need extra condition in code for handle this problem in this case

Comment: You can use something like this, @RequestMapping("/login/verify/**"), use request.getRequestURI() and then parse it.