# How to Pass URL as Path Variable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to pass a URL as a path variable, but when I input the URL as a parameter and access the route, it returns an error. I want to be able to see the address after it passes into the route as a parameter.

```
@RequestMapping("/addAddress/{address}")
public String addAddress(@PathVariable("address") String address) {
    System.out.println("Address: "+address)
    return address;
}
```

For example, if I put into the URL:

```
localhost:8080/addAddress/http://samplewebsite.com
```

I should see

```
http://samplewebsite.com
```

printed out in the back end.

Comment: @weaver: It's a "Whitelabel Error Page".

Comment: You should encode "http://samplewebsite.com" with UrlEncode. That is "http%3a%2f%2fsamplewebsite.com". Or you can encode the param to Base64 and decode it on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following;

```
@RequestMapping("/addAddress/**")
public String addAddress(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String fullUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String url = fullUrl.split("/addAddress/")[1];
    System.out.println(url);
    return url;
}
```

with `@PathVariable` that is not doable due to the `/` char breaking the behaviour you are looking for, unless you encode/decode, but I feel like this is a simpler way to go for both user of the endpoint, and for the backend.

> Also this will not fetch the request query part, e.g. `?input=user`,
>   to do that you can add [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222268/3641067)

Answer (score 4):

The forward slashes are your issue.

You have a few choices.

1. Use 2 path variables. This still works with a double forward slash. This works with URL: "localhost:8080/addAddress/http://samplewebsite.com"

   ```
   @GetMapping("/addAddress/{schema}/{address}")
   public String addAddress(@PathVariable("schema") String schema, @PathVariable("address") String address) {
       System.out.println("Address: "+ schema + "//" + address);
       return schema + "//" + address;
   }
   ```
2. Use a query (request) param, your url would then be URL: "localhost:8080/addAddress/?address=http://samplewebsite.com"

   ```
   @GetMapping("/addAddress2")
   public String addAddress2(@RequestParam("address") String address) {
       System.out.println("Address: "+address);
       return address;
   }
   ```
3. Encode the slashes in URL:

   ```
   localhost:8080/addAddress/http:%2F%2Fsamplewebsite.com"
   ```

   and configure Tomcat or Jetty, whatever you use to allow encoded slashes. Here is an example in [Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052397/spring-slash-character-in-get-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SafeUrl to parse your URL in your path.

Some documentation:

https://www.urlencoder.io/java/

It let you pass parameters safe by the url and you can decode where you need.