# RequestMapping issue with multiple Angular clients in Spring Boot Application

Tags: regex, angular, spring, spring-boot

I need to handle some GET requests in order to forward to multiple Angular clients.

```
https://example.com/web/index.html    // Client 1
https://example.com/admin/index.html  // Client 2
```

Since I don't want to use fragmented (`#`-ed) paths for `/web` things get rather annyoing.

This is my current *not working* solution:

```
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String req = request.getRequestURI();

        if (req.startsWith("/admin/")) {
            return this.redirectAdminTool(request);
        }

        return "forward:/web/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/web/{path:[^.]*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectWeb(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/web/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/{path:[^.]*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectAdminTool(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/admin/index.html";
    }
}
```

With this, what does work is accessing e.g.

- `/web/pricing`

but what does not work is accessing

- `/web/pricing/vienna`

I can access `/web/pricing` via browser, hit "*refresh*" and everything will work. But it does not for `/web/pricing/vienna`.

Now, I cannot figure out how to handle the requests and how to forward them in order to make sub-paths like `/web/pricing/vienna` to work as well.

Is there any way I can make this work?

If I change the `@RequestMapping` path to something like `/web/**` the whole thing ends up in an endless loop and breaks the server.

---

What I probably need is an expression like this:

```
/web(/[^\\.]*)
```

which would result in

```
MATCH:    /web/pricing
MATCH:    /web/specials/city
MATCH:    /web/specials/city/street
NO MATCH: /web/index.html
```

However, Spring does not like this regex: `/web(/[^\\.]*)`

In the end this issue boils down to finding a way to match everythign except static resources below `/web`.

Comment: You might be able to do this with UrlRewriteFilter - http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Hm, this solution might be my last resort but if possible I'd like to avoid having to do that. After all this here is a very small issue that could be solved with a simple regex but it seems that either `@RequestMapping` is limitted in this regard or I could not find the relevant part in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

I moved both clients to a subdirectory `a/`:

```
static/a/web
static/a/admin
```

Further, I implemented a `ForwardController` like this:

```
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/a/**/{path:[^.]*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectClients(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

        if (requestURI.startsWith("/a/admin/")) {
            return "forward:/a/admin/index.html";
        }

        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The child routes will not work because the main index needs to be loaded before, to get all the routes.
A workaround is to redirect to the main index everytime the server side does not find a path:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
public class ErrorHandlerController extends AbstractErrorController {

private static final String ROOT_PATH = "/";

public ErrorHandlerController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
    super(errorAttributes);
}

@RequestMapping
public void errorHtml(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    if(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.equals(getStatus(request))) {
        response.sendRedirect(ROOT_PATH);
    }
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return "error";
}

}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work for multiple clients. I have multiple roots `/web/index.html` and `/admin/index.html` are two separate Angular apps.