# How to let through static content and forward non-static content requests in @Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a project which runs a Spring Boot Application that serves two Angular applications in `static/`.

In order to be able to make things work, I had to move around some endoints ([see my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269565/826983)). The following works with two apps under `/a` and a REST API under `/api`:

```java
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/a/**/{path:[^.]*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectClients(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

        if (requestURI.startsWith("/a/admin/")) {
            return "forward:/a/admin/index.html";
        }

        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

}
```

The only thing *not* working is any static content that is served at the root `/` e.g. `sitemap.xml` etc.

The problem is that I am matching `/*` on the root which means any request, also `/sitemap.xml` will be caught by `ForwardController`. I have tried it with `/{path:[^.]*}` - then I can only access `/sitemap.xml` but the redirects to `/a/web/index.html` won't be reached anymore.

Actually - I don't really get why `/{path:[^.]*}` is not working here because what this should do is match anything that does not look like a static content e.g. `/a-song.wav`.

Is there a way I could make this work?

---

#### To sum it up:

I have two web application clients:

```
/a/admin/index.html
/a/web/index.html
```

and I want *any* request to the root `/` to be forwarded to `/a/web/index.html` **but** it should still be possible to access static content from the root e.g. `/sitemap.xml` and so on.

The problem is `/{path:^[.]*}` only lets me access the static files but breaks the forwarding to the clients and `/*` will work for the forwarding to the clients but makes it impossible to access static files on the root.

Comment: I remember something about the dot which is not working in the path pattern.

Comment: I find it: I had to write this `@RequestMapping(value = "/orphans/files/{siren}/{name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)` in order to make my handler work correctly (`{name:.+}` is a filename with extension). Take this like a hint, because I don't remember how I found this for my old app...

Comment: @Mohicane Thanks for the hint! I'll try this later in the evening and let you know. :)

Comment: @Mohicane I tried `/{name:^[.]+}` but it giving the same results as `/{path:^[.]*}` - for some reason both match `/sitemap.xml` :(

Comment: What version of spring are you using ?

Comment: @Veeram I am on Spring Boot 2 - don't know the *exact* version at the moment but I updated the version a few months ago.

Comment: Okay. I tried with both 1.5.19 and 2.0.1 spring boot versions. In both versions I get 404 page when I try to match /sitemap.xml. It appears to me /{path:^[.]*} is working as expected here as no match is found. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Veeram Yes, with `/{path:^[.]*}` you can now download `/sitemaps.xml` but the forwarding to `/a/web/index.html` for any non-static request will be broken. The problem is I cannot seem to be able to make *both* work.

Comment: I would try `@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/{path:[^.]*}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET) public String redirectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }` to match request at root and any other root requests.

Comment: @Veeram Nope. With that I can only access the sitemap.xml but forwarding to the web clients is broken.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the order of methods in spring MVC controller can matter and you can utilize it for your case. If you define your controller like so:

```
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sitemap.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectSitemap(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/sitemap.xml";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

    ...

}
```

Spring will first match sitemap.xml path and then, if it's not matched, go to the second one. If the number of your top-level resources is not that big, you can put them on top for priority matching.

Comment: Hm, it does work and the order does not seem to matter. Unfortunately it's not really a general solution since one has to create an endpoint for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something I would create two endpoints.

```
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/**/{path:[^.]*}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/a/**/{path:[^.]*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectClients(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

        if (requestURI.startsWith("/a/admin/")) {
            return "forward:/a/admin/index.html";
        }

        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }

}
```

Below are all the mock requests that works for me.

All root requests (/web & / & /web/2) except static is matched to first endpoint.

All static requests (/sitemap.xml & /a/web/index.html) is not matched to any endpoint and are served directly by `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`.In my case the static resources are located inside src/main/resources/static/a/web/index.html & src/main/resources/static/sitemap.xml.

All web and admin requests (/a/web & /a/admin) is matched to /a/**/{path:[^.]*}

Comment: Huh, this seems to work. :) I'll want to make some tests first but let you know if everything works now as expected!

Comment: Seems to me this works. So far no troubles :) Thanks for helping

Comment: Okay, this does **not** work. this solution will break also swallow `POST` requests which means it simply breaks the API. I wasn't able to test this sooner since I was on a break but unfortunately this answer is not the full story.