# Provide URL with @PathVariable

Tags: spring

I want to send a link in url, e.g.

> https://localhost:8080/https://www.google.com

However, this solution does not work

```
@GetMapping("/{url}")
public void writeUrl(@PathVariable String url) {
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

I need to in the @PathVariable or @RequestParam (not in @Body)

Comment: See [How to handle requests that includes forward slashes (/)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421061/how-to-handle-requests-that-includes-forward-slashes)

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/")
public void writeUrl(@RequestParam("url") String url) {
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

then:

https://localhost:8080/?url=https://www.google.com