# Spring wildcard in @RequestMapping as @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, request, mapping, wildcard

How to intercept command as @PathVariable, given such mapping:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/v1/{command}", method = {GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH})`

It works only for something like `rest/v1/info`, but not for `/rest/v1/info/more-info/and-more-info` - because I get 404. In that case, I would want my command variable to be equal to `info/more-info/and-more-info`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle requests that includes forward slashes (/)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421061/how-to-handle-requests-that-includes-forward-slashes)

Comment: It does not seem to be properly designed for a REST API. You should probably use query params for additional informations on a specific command.