# Adding PathVariable changes view path on RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a view resolver:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

and a controller:

```
@Controller
public class WorkflowListController {

 @RequestMapping(path = "/workflowlist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView index() throws LoginFailureException, PacketException,
        NetworkException {

    String profile = "dev";
    List<WorkflowInformation> workflows = workflows(profile);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("profile", profile);
    map.put("workflows", workflows);
    return new ModelAndView("workflowlist", map);
 }
}
```

and when I call the page `http://127.0.0.1:8090/workflowlist` it serves the jsp from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/workflowlist.jsp`. That all seems to work well.

However when I try to add a `@PathVariable`:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/workflowlist/{profile}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView workflowlist(@PathVariable String profile)
        throws LoginFailureException, PacketException, NetworkException {

    List<WorkflowInformation> workflows = workflows(profile);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("profile", profile);
    map.put("workflows", workflows);
    return new ModelAndView("workflowlist", map);
}
```

When I call the page `http://127.0.0.1:8090/workflowlist/dev` gives the following message:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/workflowlist/WEB-INF/jsp/workflowlist.jsp
```

Can someone explain why I'm returning the same view name in both cases but in the second example it is behaving differently?

How can I get it to work?

Comment: The path variable in the new mapping is required, so `/workflowlist` does not hit the `@RequestMapping` method and you end up with 404. You need to set up 2 mappings, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4904139/

Comment: Thanks, you highlighted a problem with my question (which I've updated). I am calling `http://127.0.0.1:8090/workflowlist/dev` in the second example. It is hitting a break point inside my controller but the generated view path is different even though I'm returning the same view name. Why?

Comment: @approxiblue - you were the only person who tried to help, so if you create an answer, I'll award you the bounty otherwise the bounty points will disappear into the ether.

Comment: Anything else I should elaborate on? I'd rather not repeat your answer.

Comment: If you know why the view resolver only takes the directory part and explain my last paragraph, then that would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why the view resolver works like that. I guess it just works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my `viewResolver`:

```
resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
```

should have been:

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
```

With a `/` at the front the path is taken from the root (webapps folder) but when the `/` is missing it becomes a relative path.

I never got an answer as to why the view resolver only took the directory part of the path but that's what appeared to happen.
It's probably so you can define subtrees of views with different roots.