# Adding Path variable changes the view path

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, redirect

I have a controller that has the following request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadUserPage(@PathVariable("id") String id) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("editUser.jsp","editUser", new User());
    modelAndView.addObject("activeUser",getActiveUserByID(id));
    return modelAndView;
}
```

and in my home.jsp, I have a href link as below

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/${eachUser.userId}">Click Here</a>
```

But when I click on the above link, the URL directs to localhost:8080/user/1234 (assuming that the user id is 1234) but it throws 404 error saying that the /user/editUser.jsp is not found. I was wondering why the "/user" is appended on to the jsp path?

And I don't hit this issue if I use @RequestParam and change the href URL to "/user?id=${eachUser.userId}".

Comment: Does this answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872026/3959856

Answer (score 1):

Both of the ways `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` working with me. Here is the test code and output. I got an error when used ".jsp" in the return statement.

```
package com.mpro.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.mpro.web.model.User;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadUserPage(@RequestParam("id") String id) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("testpage","editUser", new User());
        modelAndView.addObject("activeUser",5);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadUserPage1(@PathVariable("id") String id) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("testpage","editUser", new User());
        modelAndView.addObject("activeUser",5);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

In jsp

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user?id=5">Click Here for request parameter</a>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/5">Click Here for path variable</a>
```

and output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding the path variable argument name, in this case **id**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadUserPage(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
...
}
```

I think **@PathVariable** is used when you need to match a pattern in a uri or to get information from the uri. This is why it returns the matched uri. Mainly used in REST.

**@RequestParam** is mainly used to get a particular parameter from the url. If you need the value of id, this is when you can use **@RequestParam**.

This is what I have understood after using both of them.
Try this and tell me if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the

```
new ModelAndView("editUser.jsp","editUser", new User());
```

to

```
new ModelAndView("/editUser.jsp","editUser", new User());
```

no extra path was appended. This solved the issue.