# Spring MVC multiple requestmapping , missing requestparam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I need to handle two @RequestMapping values by one method.For example 
**/create and create/{id}**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"create","create/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String create_form(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id,Model model, @ModelAttribute("channelNode") ChannelNode channelNode,
        BindingResult result) {

      if(id>0){ //or if id exsist 

      //do something

      }

    return CHANNELNODE_ADD_VIEW;
}
```

But it doesn work when I run simple "create" url, without any param/

**It shows me following Error:**

HTTP Status 500 - Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type Long

type Status report

message Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type Long

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Spring 3.0, can I make an optional path variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not way you could do this with `@PathVariable`.

You need to do it by defining 2 separate handler methods,

1. One without path variable

   ```
    @RequestMapping(value = "create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String create_form(Model model, @ModelAttribute("channelNode") ChannelNode channelNode,
       BindingResult result) {

       return CHANNELNODE_ADD_VIEW;
    }
   ```
2. One with path variable

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "create/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String create_form(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id,Model model, @ModelAttribute("channelNode") ChannelNode channelNode,
       BindingResult result) {

       return CHANNELNODE_ADD_VIEW;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks dear ,I already know this way . But I am looking for handle both  by  one method :/ Maybe it is not possible I don't know :/

Comment: Then you need to use @RequestParam instead and send the id in query string