# Zero length part of URL in Spring controller RequestMapping PathVariable breaks resolution

Tags: java, rest, spring-web

I'm trying to make an app's REST API more RESTful and it feels like I'm not using the Spring RequestMappings in the way intended.

I have a single GET end point for doing reads:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "thing/{thingName}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getThing(
        @PathVariable(value = "thingName", required = false)
                String thingName,
        @RequestParam(value = "findByComponent", required = false)
                String findByComponentQuery,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
...
```

To be more restful, I want this endpoint to do both:

1. GET /thing/{thingName} returns a single thing having that name
2. GET /thing or /thing/ with query params returns lists of things

So in my controller, I can test whether `{thingName}` is null or zero-length and if so, check the query params for known query names.

However calling this with `http://localhost:8080/thing/?findByComponent=component123` returns a 404 from Spring with this logging:

```
12:45:18.485 PageNotFound : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/thing/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' : WARN : XNIO-1 task-3 : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

Comment: Is there any restriction that does not allow you to break this `@RequestMapping` into two different `@RequestMapping`s?

Comment: No, if it's possible. That's one thing I didn't try. I assume you mean I should create a 2nd mapping like this `@RequestMapping("thing")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not allow path variables (`{thingName}`) to be mapped to an empty `String`. In practice, this means that the URL `/thing/?findByComponent=component123` does *not* map to `thing/{thingName}` with an empty `{thingName}`, but rather, it expects there to be some mapping for `thing`. Since there is no endpoint that maps to the path `thing` (without the path variable), a `404` error is returned.

To solve this issue, you can break this single endpoint into two separate endpoints:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "thing/{thingName}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getThing(
        @PathVariable(value = "thingName") String thingName,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "thing",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getThings(,
        @RequestParam(value = "findByComponent", required = false) String findByComponentQuery,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    // ...
}
```

For more information, see [With Spring 3.0, can I make an optional path variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable).

The `required=false` flag allows for two types of requests:

1. `/thing`
2. `/thing/<some_value>`

Strictly speaking, including a trailing slash at the end of the URL (i.e. `/thing/`) means that a decision was made to include a value for the path variable, but none was provided. In the context of REST APIs, `/thing` and `/thing/` are two different endpoints, where the latter means that a value after the trailing slash was expected.

A workaround for not having to create three separate request mappings (one for each case above) is to set the `@RequestMapping` value for the controller to the base path and then have a `""` and `"/{thingName}` request mapping for the two endpoints:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("thing")
public class ThingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{thingName}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getThing(
            @PathVariable(value = "thingName") String thingName) {
        return "foo";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getThings(
            @RequestParam(value = "findByComponent", required = false) String findByComponentQuery) {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

In this case, the following mappings will occur:

1. `/thing`: `getThings`
2. `/thing/`: `getThings`
3. `/thing/foo`: `getThing`

An example of this workaround, including test cases can be [found here](https://github.com/albanoj2/ThingController).

Comment: OK, great, but does this mean I need a 3rd endpoint with `@RequestMapping("thing/")`? Spring is giving me `404` when I try `localhost:8080/thing/?findByComponent`. It seems it only likes `localhost:8080/thing?findByComponent`. My clients would complain that I'm being pedantic if I didn't allow that. I also wondered why Spring lets me specify `@PathVariable(required=false)`.

Comment: @Adam There is a little bit of nuance between having or not having a trailing slash. I've updated the answer above to explain the difference and have included a workaround so that you do not have to create 3 separate endpoints.

Comment: Hey, good explanation and makes sense - but I don't see a work-around. The only difference I see is the class-level annotation and as is, it doesn't provlde the `/thing/` endpoint - `/thing/?findByComponent=...` still returns `404`. I double-checked my code.

Comment: @Adam I've included a link in the answer to a test project that exercises all of the endpoints described in the answer. Adding the top-level `@RequestMapping` requires a change to the `@RequestMapping` for each of the endpoints as well. Be sure that the endpoints in your project reflect the `@RequestMapping` values seen in the example project.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like the way to go, but while I can get it to work with your project, I can't get `/?findByComponent=...` to resolve in my project and I can't find the difference grrrr.